# batch file with robcopy

Tags: batch-file

I use with robcopy in my batch file.
I want that if these batch file will run on OS without robcopy installed the error about it WILL appear in the loG file.the error about it is:

> 'robocopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

my code is:

```
robocopy Obl\BR "%WEBDIR%\BR"  /E /LOG+:%TMPLog% >nul
```

but this error appear only on the console not appear in TMPLog.
maybe errors of this kind should not appear in logs?
if yes what I can to do?
maybe try and catch if it exist in batch file?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my Windows 7 PC at the moment so can't really verify this thing, but would logging the *output* of `robocopy` using the `>>` redirection be the same as logging with the `/LOG+` switch? If so, you could redirect `stderr` (where the `not recognized` message is sent) to `stdout`, and `stdout` to your `%TMPLog%` file, like this:

```
robocopy Obl\BR "%WEBDIR%\BR"  /E >>%TMPLog% 2>&1
```